# Stuck on a simple recursion exercise, getting "max stack error"

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

- Sum all numbers in an array containing nested arrays
- arraySum([1,[2,3],[[4]],5]); // 15

I have written this so far ..

```
var newArray = array.slice();
    newArray = newArray.flat(Infinity);
    var sum = 0;
    if (newArray.length === 1) {
        return array[0];
    }
    if (newArray.length === 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
        if (typeof newArray[i] === "number") {
            sum += newArray[i];
        }
    }
    return arraySum(newArray);
};
```

If I put return sum it works perfect, but the exercise is calling for recursion.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use recursion, then replace the `for` loop with returning the value of the first element of the array, plus the sum of the rest of the elements in the array:

```js
const arraySum = (array) => {
  var newArray = array.slice();
  newArray = newArray.flat(Infinity);
  var sum = 0;
  if (newArray.length === 1) {
    return array[0];
  }
  if (newArray.length === 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  return array[0] + arraySum(newArray.slice(1));
};

console.log(arraySum([1,[2,3],[[4]],5]));
```

But the `.flat` seems weird to be doing on every iteration. Consider doing it only *once*, in a second default argument that gets passed along:

```js
const arraySum = (arr, arrFlat = arr.flat(Infinity)) => {
  return arrFlat.length
    ? arrFlat[0] + arraySum(arr, arrFlat.slice(1))
    : 0;
};


console.log(arraySum([1,[2,3],[[4]],5]));
```

Or check to see if the current element being iterated over is an array instead of using `.flat`, to see whether you need to iterate over the subarray with *another* recursive call to `arraySum` or just add the number:

```js
const arraySum = (arr) => {
  if (!arr.length) return 0;
  const rest = arraySum(arr.slice(1));
  return typeof arr[0] === 'number'
    ? arr[0] + rest
    : arraySum(arr[0]) + rest;
};


console.log(arraySum([1,[2,3],[[4]],5]));
```

Comment: Please offer guidance, suggestions, etc. instead of complete code samples for homework questions.